# Calculate with custom calendar week format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have got a custom calendar week format like this:

```
[YY]CW[WW].[D]
```

Example for Friday, 15.07.2022

YY => Year: "22"

CW => Fix Text: "CW"

WW => Week: "28"

D => Week Day: "5"

=> **22CW28.5**

Such a date in this format is my starting point. From there I have to do some calculations, lets say add 2 weeks. How can I do this in Excel 2013 without using Macros?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just confirm which date system you are using such that you consider 15.07.2022 to be week 28?

Comment: I use the standard 1900 date system. "=KALENDERWOCHE(HEUTE();21)" This will return 28 for 15.07.2022

Answer (score 0):

The following *messy* formulas convert between the custom date format for all dates after Jan 1st, 2000; allowing you to use standard date calculations. Sundays are 0's through to Saturdays which are 6's.

```
=TEXT(A1,"YY")  & "CW" & WEEKNUM(A1) & "." & WEEKDAY(A1,17)-1
=DATE(LEFT(A2,2)+2000,1,1)+7*(MID(A2,5,2)-1)+RIGHT(A2,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(LEFT(A2,2)+2000,1,1),17)+1
```

[image]